# Import duty tax UK if the parcel goes back without being delivered

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, commerce

I ordered a parcel from US (I live in UK) and so I paid import duty tax before delivery. Now, for weird reason FedEx didn't delivered the parcel to me and send it back to US. Now, technically there was no import duty tax since the goods have never been imported. Am I entitled to rembursement? Am I right?

Comment: The easiest would be to give the government agency a call that charged the import duty. You are surely not the first one this happened to. They might give you a refund, or refuse. If they refuse, I'd say the chance is 90% that they did so lawfully (if they give you a refund it doesn't matter whether lawfully or not).

Answer (score 1):

The goods were imported, and then re-exported. Import duty becomes payable at the point of import, regardless of what happens to the item afterwards.